# How can I update an specific value in prolog given an id?

Tags: prolog, updating

I have this program where users can sign up and use different resources from this imaginary gym, such as updating their training, weight and getting diet inputs. An user is identified by a number which is called id, and this id performs those operations. I want to update an user weight but so far I have no idea what to do. Here are some parts of my code:

this builds an user

```
 buildUser(Id, Name, Age, Weight, Height, Plan, Training, User):-
 User = user(Id, Name, Age, Weight, Height, Plan, Training).
```

and users are stored here

```
 usersData([]).
:-dynamic usersData/1.
```

these are the predicate that would update the training:

```
setWeight(Id, NewWeight):-
   retract(user(Id, Name, Age, _, Height, Plan, Training)),
   assert(user(Id, Name, Age, NewWeight, Height, Plan, Training)).

updateWeight(Data):-
   write('What's your id?: '), nl,
   readNumber(Id), nl,
   write('What is your current weight?'), nl,
   readNumber(NewWeight),
   setWeight(Id, NewWeight),
   begin(Data).
```

However, I pretty much knew that retract/assert wouldn't work. Any advices? I'm struggling really hard with prolog.

I appreciate all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're effectively storing in usersData/1, then the way to go could be

```
setWeight(Id, NewWeight):-
  retract(usersData(user(Id, Name, Age, _Weight, Height, Plan, Training))),
  assert(usersData(user(Id, Name, Age, NewWeight, Height, Plan, Training))).
```

But I think would be better to store data in user/7 instead:

```
:- dynamic user/7.

setWeight(Id, NewWeight):-
  retract(user(Id, Name, Age, _Weight, Height, Plan, Training)),
  assert(user(Id, Name, Age, NewWeight, Height, Plan, Training)).
```

SWI-Prolog syntax highlight will help you to track the correct number of fields for your dynamic predicates in your program. Also, there is library support for your use case, that simplify the maintenance of database predicates. See library([record](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=record)) and library([persistency](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=persistency)).

*edit*

Re-reading the question, I think that my first snippet above could not be on spot. Maybe this is instead what you're after...

```
setWeight(Id, NewWeight):-
  retract(usersData(UsersCur)),
  append(X,[UserCur|Y],UsersCur),
  UserCur=user(Id, Name, Age, _Weight, Height, Plan, Training),
  UserUpd=user(Id, Name, Age, NewWeight, Height, Plan, Training),
  append(X,[UserUpd|Y],UsersUpd),
  assert(usersData(UsersUpd)).
```

Now it's rather clear that storing user/7 it's better...

*edit*

A problem you should be aware of: `setWeight(UnknownId,_)` will destroy the database, because the `retract` will remain without the corresponding `assert`. So we need instead

```
setWeight(Id, NewWeight):-
  retract(usersData(UsersCur)),
  (   append(X,[UserCur|Y],UsersCur),
      UserCur=user(Id, Name, Age, _Weight, Height, Plan, Training)
  ->  UserUpd=user(Id, Name, Age, NewWeight, Height, Plan, Training),
      append(X,[UserUpd|Y],UsersUpd)
  ;   UsersUpd=UsersCur
  ),
  assert(usersData(UsersUpd)).
```

Comment: It worked wonders. You really saved me, sir. Thank you!